# Applying custom Google map style in OpenLayers2?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

Recently I stumbled upon this interesting [article](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/05/20/make-your-google-map-stand-out-with-styles/) showing potential of adding [custom styles](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps) to Google Maps. Some examples of styled maps can be seen [here](http://maps-api-tt.appspot.com/apilite/styled/styled.html) and you can design your own from scratch [here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html).

I'd like to apply 'greyscale' theme to my OpenLayers base map: 
[image]

Style description according to Google [demo](http://maps-api-tt.appspot.com/apilite/styled/styled.html) would look somehow like:

```
var styles = {
  'Greyscale': [
    {              
      featureType: 'all',
      rules: [
        {saturation: -100},
        {gamma: 0.50}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My Google map in OpenLayers currently looks simply like:

```
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets",
    {
    'numZoomLevels': 20,
    'sphericalMercator': true}
);
```

How could I apply greyscale theme to my map?

Comment: Google Maps Colorizr http://googlemapscolorizr.stadtwerk.org/ can be helpful if you want to define your own specific colours.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003578/google-maps-in-grayscale

Comment: Some examples of playing with colours: http://www.41latitude.com/post/1268734799/google-styled-maps

Comment: Don't want to let go of the bounty? :) I think simo got it

Comment: Indeed. Still three days of competition tho ;]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems that you can directly access the googlemap object using *layer.mapObject*.

Refer to gmap API to style the layer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Here is a small example page I have created: http://www.intermezzo-coop.eu/mapping/styled_gmap.html

See also the googlemap wizard : https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: Did you succeed, Radek?

Comment: @simo: I'm not sure exactly how to use 'layer.mapObject'

Comment: @radek; your going to need to create some of your own JS to define your map styling; there are several good examples on the second link there that will show you very good flow.

Comment: @radek : I haven't test it but I guess you create your gmap layer as so *var glayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(options)*, then create your style using Gmap syntax, and finally apply it doing *glayer.mapObject.mapTypes.set('hiphop', jayzMapType);* see the given exemple above. If I have some time soon, I'll try to do it and let you know

Comment: @radek : Here we go http://www.empreinte-urbaine.eu/mapping/styled_gmap.html

Comment: @simo: Many thanks! Will have a go with my server now.

Comment: The first two links seem to be broken while the third only showed me a blank map.

Comment: I applied changes to the third link

Comment: one link has been removed. Others are updated.